# Change width of items when there is less than 3 after filtering with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DJVX2/2/ that does something close to what I need.

I have a lot of items and I have a filter. When all are shown, the items are in several columns. But when I filter some times I'll get only one or two items as a result and the client wants them to be "full width", so my items need to change width after filtering when there is less than three.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 60
    }
  })

$container.isotope( 'once', 'layoutComplete',
        function( isoInstance, laidOutItems ) {
            if(laidOutItems.length<=2){

                $( ".item:not([style$='display: none;'])" ).each(function( index ) {
                    var $this = $(this);

                    if(!$this.hasClass('big')){
                        tileStyle = { width: 1048, height: 290};
                        $this.toggleClass('big');

                        $this.find('.item-content').stop().animate( tileStyle );
                    }
                    $(this).trigger('click');
                });
                $container.isotope( 'layout' );
            }
        }
    );
});
```

It does work fine on my project if I click manually on both items using the script from the fiddle, but if I try to implement it inside the layoutComplete event they will resize but they won't position properly, even when the `$container.isotope( 'layout' );` line is there.

Of course, when I click the filters I need the items to go back to their previous size but since I'm having trouble with the first part of the problem, let's find out that beforehand.

Here is a fiddle with my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/DJVX2/1305/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually toggling two times your `big` class in your `click` event. Remove one :

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        tileStyle = $this.hasClass('big') ? { width: 50, height: 50} : { width: 170, height: 110};
    //$this.toggleClass('big');

    $this.find('.item-content').stop().animate( tileStyle );

    $this.toggleClass('big');

    $this.find('.zoom').stop().animate( tileStyle );

    $container.isotope( 'layout' );

});
```

Then, I don't think you really need your `layoutComplete` event. You can just put the code when you are filtering something :

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

    // Make all items small
    $('.item').removeClass('big');
    $('.item .item-content').stop().animate({ width: 50, height: 50});

    // If filtered items are less than 3, make them wide
    if ($(filterValue).length <= 2) {
        $( ".item:not([style$='display: none;'])" ).each(function( index ) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });
    }

    $container.isotope( 'layout' );
});
```

**[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gjq30xvb/)**

Comment: Still, not the solution to my issue, the bigger squares don't position themselves properly

Comment: Ok I'm not sure to understand what you want... I'll try something

Comment: check in your example, when you refilter again the two big ones are now separated with a gap between them, that is the correct position, otherwise they overlap, but that needs to happen as soon as you filter the first time, not after you do it for the second time

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the layoutComplete event was what was crceating the problem, but I couldn't think of the obvious solution, cheers!

Comment: I need to wait until tomorrow for the bounty